# как перезапустить программу python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

есть программа и в нее добавлены исключения

```
print("start")
try:
   val = int(input("input number: "))
   tmp = 10 / val
   print(tmp)
except Exception as e:
   print("Error! " + str(e))
print("stop")
```

и если сработает исключение вывести ошибку и перезапустить программу

Comment: Это конечно очень старное решение, но и очень веселый) можно в случае ошибки создавать еще раз програму, а старая програма самоуничтожется, если нужно будет подробно напишите)

Comment: @peter можно поподробнее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хорошо, говорю поподробней)

```
import subprocess 
subprocess.call('Здесь путь к файлу')
```

Важно заметить что путь должен быть в примере C:/Users и так далее, тоесть через /

это открывает, что бы закрыть нужно прописать вот это:

```
subprocess.check_output('taskkill /im Здесь название програмы')
```

Я думаю что немного иформации я дал, единственное что код может остановить новый процес, а не старый, поетому я вам посоветую копировать код в новый файл, с новым название и просто чередовать два файла)

Comment: `/IM` это имя процесса, у питонов это будет `python.exe`/`pythonw.exe`, лучше через pid закрывать

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант

```
print("start")

while True:                                  # +++ 
    try:
       val = int(input("input number: "))
       tmp = 10 / val
       print(tmp)
       break                                 # +++ 
    except Exception as e:
       print("Error! " + str(e))
   
print("stop")
```

Comment: Как вариант, поместить `break` в секцию `else:` конструкции `try:`. Просто чтобы не маячил в основной секции и всегда был последним.

Comment: а можно для меня для чайника объяснить (как бы все работает,просто для саморазвития). Для чего надо писать `break` к конструкции `try`:

Comment: @Marlin09  https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/cikly-for-i-while-operatory-break-i-continue-volshebnoe-slovo-else.html